# Error: SSL provisioning FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE in Cloud Run (GCP)

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, vite, google-cloud-run

I have a repo in github which has vue.js application and nodejs also

1. I create a github action
2. Through action it will create the docker image and push into artifact registry in GCP
3. From artifact registry it will deploy to Cloud RUN and also GKE
4. In Cloud RUN i added intergation of Custom domains - Google Cloud Load Balancing
5. After intergation i given domain name and copied IP Address and past into godaddy 'A' records
6. After Successfully Integration domain name show Active status
7. After that i login into Manage.Auth0.com and added domain name there
8. After that i enter domain name in browser i got login page after login i got 404 page not found
9. Even i try domain name like https://www.cloud.test.co/home and https://www.cloud.test.co/dashboard both show me 404 page not found
10. Then i troubleshoot myself like dig cloud.test.co and in browser i click on inspect and nslookup also below you can find screenshot.

Here is the Error of SSL got fail screenshot:

[image]

Here is the godaddy IP Add added:

[image]

Here is the screenshot custom domain mapping:

[image]

Troubleshooting information:

```
$ dig 34.xx.xx.249

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.18-Ubuntu <<>> 34.xx.xx.249
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 22961
;; flags: qr rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;34.xx.xx.249. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
34.xx.xx.249. 0 IN A 34.xx.xx.249

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 172.21.208.1#53(172.21.208.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jan 19 12:22:46 IST 2024
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 58
```

`nslookup`

```
$ nslookup 34.xx.xx.249
249.xx.xx.34.in-addr.arpa name = 249.xx.xx.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Which is best to create custom domain mapping in below 1 and 2

1. Custom domains - Google Cloud Load Balancing
2. Cloud Run Domain Mappings

Comment: Before you create a custom domain mapping, the DNS settings must be correct. Are you trying to do it in the reverse order?

Comment: you only tell me what DNS settings im missing. first i click on cloud run then click on integrate to cloud loadbalancer after that i  create custom domain mapping after that i got ip address and then i copied that ip address paste into godaddy in A records after 30mint i got SSL Fail that the procedure i have follow even google docs also i have follow same method

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Research DNS Negative Caching. The DNS resource records must be correct first, not sometime later.

Comment: ok anyway i got understand DNS settings for custom domain mapping. Now i want to know why cloud.test.co/home or cloud.test.co/dashboard both showing 404 not found  even cloud.test.co page comes as login after that i got 404 not found. Can u just tell me what i need to do solve this issue

Comment: Please put details in your question and not via comments. Also, clearly describe one problem and not generalized descriptions. If you have multiple problems, post multiple questions.

Comment: i already describe in question and let me write in clear format